# Elements get scramble when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

I am new to web design and it's really hard for me to fix this problem.

The elements are in position when the browser is maximized. But when the browser resizes the elements get scrambled. Especially the, the  second picture, and the "Welcome to Snaptastic Photobooth"

HTML CODE:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <head>
        <title> Snaptastic Photo Booth </title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "web.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "nav.css">
    </head>

    <body>
     <div class = "header">
     <img src = "imgs/Header.jpg" width = 500 height = 450 alt = "Snaptastic Photobooth">
     </div>

    <div class = "mainNav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href = "#">Gallery</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">Reservation</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </div>

   <div class = "rsidebar">
   <ul>
   <li><a href = "https://www.facebook.com/Photoboothsnaptastic?fref=ts">Like us on Facebook!</a></li> 
   </ul>
   </div>

   <div class = "container">
   <img src = "imgs/Header1A.jpg" width = 472 height = 62 alt = "Snaptastic  Photobooth">
   <h2> Welcome to Snaptastic Photo Booth! </h2>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

CSS:

```
   body {
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Basketville, serif;
   background: url(imgs/bg1.jpg) repeat-x;
   background-size: cover;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
   }

   .header {
   margin: 0 0 0 39%;
   }

   body img {
   border-radius:15px;
   }

   .container {
   position: absolute;
   float: left;
   top: 45%;
   left: 28%;
   right: 25%;
   opacity: 0.9;
   }

  .container img {
  padding: 0 0 0 25%;
  }

  .container h2 {
   padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: Agency FB;
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   background: url(imgs/wp1.jpg);
 }
```

Comment: Please, make a fiddle!

Comment: Difficult to tell you without a fiddle, but I don't get the CSS rules of .container. Why do you use float and position: absolute at the same time ? Can you reproduce your layout in a fiddle with some placeholder images (you can use http://lorempixel.com/ for example).

Answer (score 0):

First their is confusion in identifying *maximize* from *resize*. well, In order to write for responsive web, first you have to get rid of fixed pixel values i.e. `<img src = "imgs/Header1A.jpg" **width = 472 height = 62** alt = "Snaptastic  Photobooth">`. Also, not only this layout is scrambled on small screen (as it should because of fixed img width and height values) but it is scrambled on Browser's full window too. you use left:28% and right:25% which doesn't add up to give 50% out of 100% window size. surely it is pushing the .container to right side by 3% which causes to orient 'NOT IN THE MIDDLE' of window. Another reason: you are using

```
.container img {
  padding: 0 0 0 25%;
  }
```

which will cause the img element to **always** stay to right side of window no matter what the screen size is. Also, you are not using media queries to target different sizes as to your demand.